# Bytescout.Spreadsheet Number Formatting Multiplying By 100

Tags: c#, excel

I'm currently using the bytescout library to generate a PDF document. Here is some pseudo code of me setting the cell in question:

```
cell.Value = 20;
cell.NumberFormatString = "0.00%";
```

When the Excel document is generated the Cell displays as 2000.00%

Does anyone have experience with this library?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is to divide by 100. Seems Excel expects the % decimal value. The lightbulb eventually came on.